# What times do I need to beat to get Fly The Co-op?

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-iv

For the achievement/trophy `Fly The Co-op` you need to:

> Beat our time in versions of "Deal Breaker", "Hangman's NOOSE" and "Bomb da Base II"

What times do you have to beat?

**My findings so far...**

In-game I cannot see where these times are posted.  Scrolling down the posted times doesn't highlight anything to indicate the tag/name is a Rockstar employee/time.

The best I could find online (via numerous resources, mainly achievement/trophy guides on youtube and achievement/trophy guide websites) the following times are given:

- **Hangman's Noose:** 2:32
- **Bomb da Base II:** ranges between 5:32 and 5:34
- **Deal Breaker:** 7:03

Unfortunately, the times in game also include milliseconds.  Scanning down a few people who posted over 2:32 on Hangman's Noose (e.g. 2.32.001 onwards) shows that they still got the achievement/trophy, but then some don't (as they didn't beat all 3 times).  It is pretty hard to track their scores on the other leaderboards (well, very time consuming).

Now, there are people who the achievement/trophy with scores at 2.33 onwards.  Some appear to be cheaters or somehow glitched the requirements.

I would say that the times are very likely in these ranges but cannot see the exact actual times you must beat.

Why is this question important?  Well, the number of skilled people have pretty much moved onto other games so it is very hard to jump into a random lobby full of people able to get near the times.  My time in Bomb da Base was `5:33:017` but not sure if I need to go back to that one.  It took maybe 3 evenings to finally get a group together to hit the time.  I doubt any more than 6 or 7 people are looking for a game at any one time so you are pretty much stuck with the same selection of people for a few hours.

Note - I'm not asking for specific help, rather the actual *specific* requirements (not a rounded up time).  I cannot see the exact times online in any official capacity. Maybe I missed the official word from Rockstar in some forum post or guide.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no official record of the specific time including decimals. The seconds vary, and this is most likely because people have tried and failed to find these times. It doesn't seem like anyone has bothered trying and failing to find the decimals required to get the achievement. With other words; **the decimals are currently unknown**.

The times you've found are mostly the same times I've found as well, and the times you've found seem to be the fastest times. As long as you've finished the mission with a good margin to these times, the achievement/trophy should appear.

Comment: Also worth mentioning; if you got a lot of time on your hands, you may look into the code of the game itself and maybe find the exact times there?